# Htmlagilitypack get all nodes, not just FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

`var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"announcementsContainer\"]/div[1]/div[2]").Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().Attributes["href"].Value;`
How can I change the "FirstOrDefault()", so that I can get all available nodes, not just the first? Thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Select()` method from `System.Linq`.

```
var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"announcementsContainer\"]/div[1]/div[2]").Descendants("a").Select(d => d.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Comment: Thank you, I would have never though of this. -It works perfectly!